# Android Tab Layout Tutorial -deprecated things-

Tags: android, layout, activitygroup

I continued to do [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/) tutorial. In this tutorial, guy used this code;

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
```

in this code `TabActivity` deprecated. Then I used `extends ActivityGroup` , it was also deprecated. I searched and I found `extends Fragment` , but I couldn't apply `extends Fragment` to tutorials' code. So how can I fix it please ?

Comment: Have a look at the below link for details.

[android-tab-layout-tutorial-deprecated-things][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297293/andorid-how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-tabhost