# How to implement tabs in Android now that TabHosts are deprecated?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, instagram

I am trying to implement five tabs in a similar look and feel as the **Instagram app**. What is the best practice for this now that TabHost and TabActivity are deprecated?

I want to have the five tabs at the top of the screen (below the Action Bar), each having a drawable representing the content of that tab.

Since the tabs will always be shown I want to have them in one Activity. The content of each tab however will be dependent on which tab has been pressed. Therefore I want to have a view in the same Activity below the tabs in which I load the fragments in, one at a time depending on which is pressed.

So to sum up:
I want to have **one Activity** with the tabs at the top and a view below them in which I load one of **five different fragments** at a time.

Please help me making this possible without using deprecated classes:)

Comment: Check this answer maybe?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297293/android-how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-tabhost

Answer (score 1):

You can use this two new class for creating tabs [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java), [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java), you must pass a ViewPager with some Fragments to this class, for a custom view on each tab use `setCustomTabView`. you can find examples with google.

EDIT:

for custom layout (mine contain both image and text) setup your tab like this:

```
slideTab = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.getbook_sliding_tabs);
slideTab.setDistributeEvenly(true);
slideTab.setCustomTabView(R.layout.cat_tab_layout, R.id.main_tab_title);
```

the `cat_tab_layout` :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:background="@drawable/cat_tab_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_tab_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cat_all_book_icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_tab_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tab1"
        android:textColor="@color/medium_gray"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_tab_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

do some change in `populateTabStrip()` form `SlidingTabLayout` class:

```
adapter = (GetBookFragmentPagesAdapter)mViewPager.getAdapter();// get your view pager adapter
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
....
if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
    // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
    tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip, false);
    tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);

    ImageView tabImage = (ImageView)tabView.findViewById(R.id.main_tab_image);
    tabImage.setImageResource(adapter.getImages(i)); // getImage() return image id for each tab

}
```

....

then you will end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Does the SlidingTabLayout let me change the tabs from text to icons? I cannot find an example where this has been made. If this is possible this solution is interresting.

Comment: @epoxy: sure you can put any custom layout, i have done it in my app:), please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to implement five tabs in a similar look and feel as the Instagram app

Since not everybody uses Instagram, in the future, please post a screenshot of what you want somewhere, and link to it from your question.

> I want to have one Activity with the tabs at the top and a view below them in which I load one of five different fragments at a time.

[Use `FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentTabHost.html). Or, use `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator (e.g., `TabPageIndicator` with the `IconPagerAdapter` from [the ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)).

Comment: In the FragmentTabHost-API it says:
"You will not normally use this, instead using action bar tabs."

Is this bad practice somehow? Do you have an example of where FragmentTabHost has been implemented successfully?:)

Comment: @epoxy: "Is this bad practice somehow?" -- that comment in the documentation is out of date. I filed [an issue about that](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73538) about 9 months ago. "Do you have an example of where FragmentTabHost has been implemented successfully?:) " -- no, as most everyone is using `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator.