# My listview values are reloading when i swipe one fragment to another in android?

Tags: java, android

i am using a tabHost for 4 fragments in this fragments i am calling custom adapters for each fragment when i move from one fragment to another fragment my list view is reloading freshly i dont want to refresh my listview from moving one fragment to another

Help me guys

Comment: start with writing a good question when we have to read through all this stuff without capitals and interpunction and have to constantly backtrack our eyes in an attempt to understand what you are writing do you actually think that people will make the effort it is in your interest to write questions that are easy to read if you want people to help you that is just simple statistical reasoning to get more people to read your question so click the edit keyword and start fixing this wall of text some code would help as well how are we supposed to understand what you are doing without that

Answer (score 0):

Make your data object the member of your activity that is initializing the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297293/android-how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-tabhost) out. I would recommend using a ViewPager with a tabbed indicator, or a set of custom buttons linked to the pager. I've implemented this solution in several apps where each fragment contains heavy content, and the performance was great. Create all your fragments, and setup the pager on each change, this way the content of your "tabs" will stay the same on user switching.